# How can I put MYINSTITUTE in the top bar of a beamer theme?

Tags: beamer, themes

I have modified a theme (PaloAlto) in beamer in order to have my own theme, but I have not finished yet. I have two colored bars in top and left margins, an image in left upper corner and a transparent image in the center of all of the slides. What do I want now?

I want to put MYINSTITUTE (in white color) in the top margin bar only in the (first) title slide. How can I do this? (You can use PaloAlto theme to explain your answer. Thank you in advance.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{IPN} %My theme based on PaloAlto

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{default}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{fancybox} % To use boxes
\usepackage{tikz} % To put transparent logo on the center of slide
\usepackage{graphicx} % To include graphics
\usepackage{ragged2e} % To justify text

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} %no navigation symbols on right bottom side of slide
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}%{transparent} % Transparent paused text


%%% Seccion del titulo y autor
\title{MYTITLE}
\subtitle[MYSUBTITLE]{MYSUBTITLE}
\author{MYSELF}
\institute{MYINSTITUTE}
\date{\today}
%%%
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
     \titlepage
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, and what is inside `IPN`??? It's difficult to answer without it

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Basically the same than in PaloAlto theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the argument of `\begin{frame}` to set the frame title/top bar

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usetheme{IPN} %My theme based on PaloAlto
\usetheme{PaloAlto}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{default}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{fancybox} % To use boxes
\usepackage{tikz} % To put transparent logo on the center of slide
\usepackage{graphicx} % To include graphics
\usepackage{ragged2e} % To justify text

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} %no navigation symbols on right bottom side of slide
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}%{transparent} % Transparent paused text

\newcommand{\myinstitute}{MYINSTITUTE}

%%% Seccion del titulo y autor
\title{MYTITLE}
\subtitle[MYSUBTITLE]{MYSUBTITLE}
\author{MYSELF}
\institute{\myinstitute}
\date{\today}
%%%
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{\myinstitute}
     \titlepage
  \end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  Other content
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, that gave me an idea to solve it. Best regards!

Comment: @R.Parada: In your first message you complained ;-) Well, you did not write, that you want to remove the Institute title from the text content...

Comment: Righ, sorry.

    \title{MYTITLE}
    \subtitle[MYSUBTITLE]{MYSUBTITLE}
    \author{MYSELF}
    %\institute{MYINSTITUTE}
    \date{\today}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{\Huge {\hspace {0.25cm}MYINSTITUTE}\\ \large \hspace{0.9cm}MYFACULTY}
     \titlepage
    \end{frame}
    \end{document}

Thank you very much. Best regards.

Comment: I do not know why it appears unformatted. I left four spaces before writing code. Sorry.